# /dev/disk-by-uuid/* permissions = lrwxrwxrwx... Is this a security risk?

Tags: permissions, security, partitioning, uuid, hacking

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

Output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 sep 15 11:34 49e9738d-627e-... -> ../../sdb5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 sep 15 11:34 7ad390da-d1a2-... -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 sep 15 11:34 7b47ed89-5244-... -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 sep 15 11:34 be7d4a16-5c69-... -> ../../sda1
```

From above output we can understand from the third `rwx` that everybody has permission to read, write and execute these files.

Does that mean that an attacker who has no physical access to the machine (and isn't the owner or in the group the owns the files) can do something harmful to `/dev/sdXY`, due to these permissions?

If yes... should we change these permissions to `lrwxrwx---`?

Comment: @Zanna I'm talking about output of : ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid

I'll edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions on `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` are only the permissions for the links, not the permissions for the device referenced by the link.

**Example**

Here is the permissions on one of my partitions, in `/dev/disk/by-uuid`:

```
pim@pim-linux:~$ ls -lh /dev/disk/by-uuid/84bb8e1e-56a7-413c-82dc-c7f0d23d6059 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov  6 07:57 /dev/disk/by-uuid/84bb8e1e-56a7-413c-82dc-c7f0d23d6059 -> ../../sdb2
```

You can see that `/dev/disk/by-uuid/84bb8e1e-56a7-413c-82dc-c7f0d23d6059` is a symbolic links to `/dev/sdb2` with all permissions (`lrwxrwxrwx`).

Now let's have a look at the permissions of `/dev/sdb2`:

```
pim@pim-linux:~$ ls -lh /dev/sdb2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 18 Nov  6 07:57 /dev/sdb2
```

`/dev/sdb2` is a block device, owned by root, and only root (and the root group is able to read or write to it.

Let's try messing up with the partition, (as my normal user *pim*):

```
pim@pim-linux:~$ echo test > /dev/disk/by-uuid/84bb8e1e-56a7-413c-82dc-c7f0d23d6059 
bash: /dev/disk/by-uuid/84bb8e1e-56a7-413c-82dc-c7f0d23d6059: Permission denied
```

Success! `permision denied` is what we expected.

**About the attacker**

The potential attacker (either local or remote) must have gained root privileges on your machine before messing with your disk, so the permissions on the `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` links are not a security problem.

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT** change the permissions.

Compare the results of `ls -l -L /dev/disk/by-uuid`, or inspect the whole structure, where it makes more sense, with `ls -l -R /dev/disk`, and of course, read `man ls` or http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ls.1.html . If your terminal has the capabilities, use the `--color=auto` option in the `ls` commands. You can have `ls` tell you the `inode` number with the `-i` option, so my recommended command is:

```
/bin/ls -l -R -i --color=auto /dev/disk
```

The initial `l` (of `lrwxrwxrwx`) indicates a "soft link", a pointer (evaluated at runtime) to another filesystem object. The other filesystem object's permissions control access.